# Populating ObservableCollection in a different thread

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a class that inherits IEnumerable to retrieve a collection of `DataType`.

```
class DataCollector : IEnumerable<DataType>
{
    public IEnumerator<DataType> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // this takes from 5 to 20 seconds,
        // so I want it to run in a background thread.
    } 
}
```

For now DataType is pretty simple with just a *Name* and *Value* property.

In my ViewModel:

```
private AsyncObservableCollection<DataType> _Data = new AsyncObservableCollection<DataType>();
```

I'm using `AsyncObservableCollection` from [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/04/17/wpf-binding-to-an-asynchronous-collection/) so I can populate it from the BackgroundWorker.

The constructor in ViewModel creates a BackgroundWorker, this is the DoWork:

```
void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var data = new DataCollector();
    foreach (var i in data)
    {
        _Data.Add(i);
    }
}
```

I'm getting `Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.`
Does this mean I need to create the `DataType` that i'm yielding from DataCollector.GetEnumerator() in the UI thread? How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just wait for the whole thing to finish, and then marshal the insertion of the items to the UI thread?

```
void BackgroundWorker_Completed(ect... Im not used to work with BW so I don't know the parameters)
{
    _Data.AddRange(yourdataItems);
}
```

**Edit**:

If you want to progressively populate the observablecollection:

```
void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var data = new Datacollector();
    foreach (var i in data)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(_Data.Add(i)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to solve the `Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.` exception.

Comment: @Josh post the full code. That can't be. Post the `DataType` and the iterator code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the capability to upgrade to .NET 4.5, one of the improvements to WPF for that version is the ability to modify collections on background threads. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588.aspx#xthread_access) for more information.

Otherwise, in previous you should probably attempt to only modify the collection on the UI thread, through the use of `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` or `Dispatcher.Invoke` or another synchronization mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object (ObservableCollection) back with BackGroundWorker ReportProgess

[BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress Method (Int32, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx)

Pass back 100 or a 1000 rows at a time.
Or just pass back the first 1000 and then wait for the complete to get the total.